# Background load before the image - angular js

Tags: css, angularjs

Hi  when I load the page I see the background of "images class" loading before the ng-src image is load

is there a way to fix that?

using Angular js

```
    <div class="images" >
         <img ng-if="expression" class="imgclass" ng-src="{{vm.src  ||  '//:0' }}" /> 
             <img ng-if="!expression" class="imgclass" ng-src="absolute url" /> 
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
<div class="images" ng-if="loaded===true" >
  <img ng-if="expression" class="imgclass" ng-src="{{vm.src  ||  '//:0' }}" ng-init="loaded = true"/> 
  <img ng-if="!expression" class="imgclass" ng-src="absolute url" ng-init="loaded = true"/> 
</div>
```